# Search through multiple fields in Django

Tags: python, django, django-views

I'm trying to build a search system, and I want to search by multiple fields`name, state, city,` in my django models. I wrote the below code, yet I've been unable to figure out how to go about it.

Models:

```
class Finhall(models.Model):
     user=models.ForeignKey(User)
     name=models.CharField(max_length=250, unique=True)
     address=models.CharField(max_length=200)
     city=models.CharField(max_length=200)
     state=models.CharField(max_length=200)

     def __unicode__(self):
         return u'%s' % (self.name)
```

Views.py

```
def hup_find(request):
    if ('q' in request.GET) and request.GET['q'].strip():
        query_string=request.GET.get('q')
        seens=Finhall.objects.filter(name__icontains=query_string)
    else:
        seens=None
    return render_to_response('find.html',{'seens':seens},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Template:

```
 {% block content %}
     <body>
    <form action="" method="GET">
    <input type="text" name="q" />
    <button type="submit">search</button>
   </form>


    {% for seen in seens %}

    <p> {{seen.name}}</p>

    {% empty %}

      <p> no search </p>
    {% endfor %}

 </body>

   {% endblock %}
```

How can I go about this? I don't want to use haysatck due to some personal reasons.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

you can use django [`Q`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) objects to do `OR` query,

or if you want to `AND`your queries together just use the current lookups as kwargs

```
seens = Finhall.objects.filter(
  name__icontains=query_string, 
  address__icontains=query_string
)
```

You should really consider full text search or `haystack` (which makes search easy) because `icontains` issues a `%LIKE%` which is not remotely scalable

Comment: Hi what about if I want to search by the user? ie user=models.ForeignKey(User). Your solution did not work because I think I am searching by foreign key and it returned an error

Answer (score 13):

EDIT: Just noticed it is Postgres only

Apparently in django 1.10 [SearchVector](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/postgres/search/#searchvector) class was added.

Usage from the docs:

> Searching against a single field is great but rather limiting. The Entry instances we’re searching belong to a Blog, which has a tagline field. To query against both fields, use a SearchVector:

```
>>> from django.contrib.postgres.search import SearchVector
>>> Entry.objects.annotate(
...     search=SearchVector('body_text', 'blog__tagline'),
... ).filter(search='Cheese')
[<Entry: Cheese on Toast recipes>, <Entry: Pizza Recipes>]
```

Answer (score 9):

To search same text in multiple fields you can use this :

```
from django.db.models import Q

class SearchAPI(APIView):
    def get(self, request, search_text, format=None, **kwargs):
        Model.objects.filter(Q(search_tags__contains=search_text) | Q(auto_tags__contains=search_text)
```

Answer (score 5):

As [Robin Nemeth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4050925/robin-nemeth) suggested, if you are using postgres db, can use the SearchVector, (I'm just making it straight to the question, get full details in [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/postgres/search/#searchvector).)

First add `django.contrib.postgres` to the `INSTALLED_APPS`, helps leveraging PostgreSQL’s full text search engine.

in the views.py of the search,

```py
from django.contrib.postgres.search import SearchVector


# view function
def hup_find(request):
  search_vector = SearchVector('name', 'state', 'city')

  if ('q' in request.GET) and request.GET['q'].strip():
    query_string=request.GET['q']
    seens = Findhall.objects.annotate(
                search=search_vector).filter(search=query_string)

  return render(request, 'find.html', {'seens':seens})
```

For large databases the search process takes some time, you can improve the performance using use GIN-(Generalized Inverted Index) feature of postgresql, These are some helpful links other than the official [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/postgres/search/#performance),

- [Mastering django Search](https://django.cowhite.com/blog/mastering-search-in-django-postgres/).
- This [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53799552/django-full-text-search-optimization-postgres).

There is different approach found, I think employing search in a more pythonish way by [Julien Phalip](https://www.julienphalip.com/blog/adding-search-to-a-django-site-in-a-snap/),

Comment: For your different approach.